# How to close exit and restart program

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a program and Im checking if there is an instance running, and if there is an instance running it should terminate the running program and run my app.. before I was just prompting the user that there is a running instance and just close the program. Now the user want the program to just terminate that instance and launch the app.

```
if (Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)).Length > 1)
{
 //MessageBox.Show("Another instance of the Program is Running", Global.ProgName, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
 //Environment.Exit(0);
 foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)))
 {
    process.Kill();
 }
 Process.Start(Path.GetFileName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location));
}
```

Comment: Is it a different instance of the same app or a totally different app? There is actually a low level API for handling single instance apps. What you should actually do is not kill the other process, but instead send a message to it saying its being re-awakened and then exit out of this process without doing anything else. Then the other process will open the window or reset to the default view or whatever it does. There is a win32 api for handling this from .NET that works pretty well, I'll look for it.

Comment: Well, that's all very interesting. But what is your _question_? You seem to already have a means for identifying the running process, and a means for terminating it. Have you made any attempt whatsoever to start the different process you want started? What is it you actually need help with here?

Comment: @justin.m.chase still same app

Comment: @PeterDuniho please look at my code. i didn't success in my goal of terminating same app running and relaunching it again. I try process kill and restart the app [didn't work

Comment: @justin.m.chase Ill wait for your answer

Comment: some downvote? why?

Comment: Here look at this: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/4430/single-instance-application-in-c

You shouldn't kill the other process as that can cause data loss or other errors depending on what the app is doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(Process.GetProcessesByName(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)).Length > 1)
{
    foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)))
    {
        if (process.Id != Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id)
        {
            process.Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

This code gets the processes which has same name with yours and kills the old ones, new one is the killer one.

[image]

Comment: this works like a magic.. This what I need. Thank you so much @Bulutay

Comment: You are welcome! The logic was like, "if there is some processes with same name and their ids are different, kill them." (We don't want to kill current process, that's why we checked for ids.)

Comment: yes.. that is also the thing that comes in my mind, if only i can trigger something unique with the 2.. and you provide the answer, their process ID.. thanks again men

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clean, but you could use a shell command:

```
ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo();
Info.Arguments = "/C ping 127.0.0.1 -n 4 && cd \"" + Application.StartupPath + "\" &&  filename.exe";
Info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Info.CreateNoWindow = true;
Info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
t.Elapsed += T_Elapsed;
t.Start();
Process.Start(Info);

private void T_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

The shell command pings localhost 4 times to pass time, and during those pings, the program exits. The original shell command is still running after the program exits, so the program re-opens after the pings.

Comment: Cool.. I will try this one